# How to get file directory trough .htaccess by using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]`?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, directory, rewrite

How to get file directory trough .htaccess by using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA]`?

If .htaccess is located in `http://localhost/some/dir/.htaccess` and I'm opening `http://localhost/some/dir/here/I/use/RewriteRule/`, how I detect value `/some/dir/` without using `RewriteBase` and without manual adding `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/some/dir/`, like value `localhost` I get trough `%{HTTP_HOST}`?

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite does not know what portion of the URL got it to a specific directory, which is why RewriteBase is needed to generate proper links for relative substitutions in all but the simplest case.

You have to bake this info into your ruleset.